# Elixir/PhoenixFramework - How do I get test.secret.exs to automatically load in test environment?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

It seems as though `test.secret.exs` does not load up automatically in the  `test` environment.

`Application.get_env(:my_app, :my_settings)` returns `nil` even though my `test.secret.exs` contains the following:

```
use Mix.Config

config :my_app, :my_settings,
  setting1:      "blah",
  setting2:      "bleh"
```

I'm running Elixir 1.4.0.

Comment: Do you have `import_config "test.secret.exs"` at the end of `test.exs` like `prod.exs` has?

Comment: Should I need to do this when the following is in `config.exs`?
`import_config "#{Mix.env}.exs"`

Comment: Yes, that imports `test.exs`. `test.exs` should import `test.secret.exs` like `prod.exs` does.

Comment: Gotcha. Submit an answer! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prod.secret.exs` is explicitly loaded by `prod.exs` with this line present at the end in the default Phoenix app template:

```
import_config "prod.secret.exs"
```

`test.exs` does not have this by default, so if you want to load `test.secret.exs`, you can add the following at the end of `test.exs`:

```
import_config "test.secret.exs"
```

Comment: Thanks again, Dogbert! You saved the day. You're like my Elixir Guardian Angel. :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Dogbert's answer, for those who want a DRY solution for loading the respective `*.secret.exs` file for each environment, you can put this into `config/config.exs`:

```
import_config "#{Mix.env}.secret.exs"
```

With that in there, you can remove the `import_config` function call from each environment-specific config file.